# How to change a simple network dataframe to a correlation table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is in this format

```
  from to weight
0    A  D 3
1    B  A 5
2    C  E 6
3    A  C 2
```

I wish to convert this to a correlation-type dataframe which would look like this -

```
  A B C D E
A 0 0 2 0 3
B 5 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 6
D 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0
```

I thought a possible (read naïve) solution would be to loop over the dataframe and then assign the values to the correct cells of another dataframe by comparing the rows and columns.

Something similar to this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = sorted(set(df["from"])), index =sorted(set(df["from"])))

for i in range(len(df)):
    cor.loc[df.iloc[i,0], df.iloc[i,1]] = df.iloc[i,2]
```

And that worked. However, I've read about not looping over Pandas dataframes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/10949324).

The primary issue is that my dataframe is larger than this - a couple thousand rows. So I wish to know if there's another solution to this since this method doesn't sit well with me in terms of being Pythonic. Possibly faster as well, since speed is a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is a pivot with reindex:

```
(df.pivot(index='from', columns='to', values='weight')
 .reindex(all_vals)
 .reindex(all_vals,axis=1)
 .fillna(0)
)
```

Output:

```
to      A    B    C    D    E
from                         
A     0.0  0.0  2.0  3.0  0.0
B     5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0
D     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
E     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is `all_vals` here?

Comment: `df.pivot('from','to','weight').fillna(0)` should do the trick too to keep only the final values.

Comment: @Abhishek `all_vals =  ['A','B','C','D','E']` so as you can have all the columns/rows.

Comment: @filippo `df[['from', 'to']].stack().unique()` or just use `np.unique(df[['from', 'to']])` for performance